# terminal bell sound interrupting

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

```
loc="locationA"
usr="user1"
fw_loc=$(</home/user/Desktop/FW_RULES.txt)

ssh -A -tt user2@192.168.1.2 <<ABC
fw_orig="$fw_loc"
fw_cmpr=\$(ssh root@$loc -o LogLevel=ERROR uci show firewall)
wc --lines <<<"\$fw_orig"
wc --lines <<<"\$fw_cmpr"
diff -s <(echo "\$fw_orig") <(echo "\$fw_cmpr")
exit
ABC
```

I have a script where I load local text file to variable in HERE document. Text file has approx. 370 lines. Then I take firewall rules from another server and try to compare if FW rules match. However, after line *fw_orig="$fw_loc"* shell automatically expands variable (not actually needed though) and terminal makes beep sound and makes interruptions in text, like so:

```
[user2@jump ~]$ fw_orig="firewall.defaults=defaults
>firewall.poplanhttp3=rule
l
> firewall.poplanhttp3.name='poplanhttp3'
> firewall.lanpopchhttp2.name='lanpopahttp5'
> firewal
> firewall.lanpopchhttp2.dest='POPA'
.
firewall.poplanssh2.dest_port='27'
i
> firewall.poplanssh2.target='ACCEPT'
/
```

text is interrupted at different lines each time I run it.
why do those interruptions with sound happen and how can I avoid it ?
Interesting this is, that later in my script I compare both variables, and number of lines matches, but diff command finds differences between variables in all interruptions of "$fw_orig".

***EDIT***
when I tried to write variable to file and then compare it:

```
echo "\$fw_orig">/home/user2/file
..
..
diff -s <(echo "\$fw_orig") /home/user2/file
```

dif command returned:

```
Files /dev/fd/63 and /home/user2/file are identical
```

maybe it can help understand what's going on .. however, file <> variable comparison works, variable <> variable comparison doesn't work ..

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify the example, focusing only on the faulty line and some of its prerequisites, and eliminate the unnecessary steps (such as ssh).

The `fw_loc` variable contains the contents of a file. It sure has plenty of newlines and plenty of spaces; presumably other special characters too.

Whereas I don't see the contents of that file, I try to be evil. So here's the stripped-down version of what you're doing, with some imaginary evil contents from that file:

```
fw_loc='foo"; rm -rf "/ouch'

cat <<ABC
fw_orig="$fw_loc"
ABC
```

If you execute this, you'll see that this prints

```
fw_orig="foo"; rm -rf "/ouch"
```

In your particular case, it's not `cat`ed but sent to the remote host to execute.

The level of escaping is clearly not sufficient. I believe this is the reason for the weird behavior you're experiencing, although I'm not sure what special characters it fails on in your case.

One possible approach is to escape the value so that a subsequent assigmnent in bash (on the remote side) will work properly using `printf %q`:

```
fw_loc='foo"; rm -rf "/ouch'

cat <<ABC
fw_orig=$(printf %q "$fw_loc")
ABC
```

Take care to use double quotes immediately around the variable reference `$fw_loc` (otherwise `printf` doesn't do its job properly), but not around the `$(...)` command substitution (because `printf %q` relies on its output not being within quotes)!

This prints

```
fw_orig=foo\"\;\ rm\ -rf\ \"/ouch
```

which is equivalent to `fw_loc`'s definition above.

You might need to apply this trick a few more times further on in your script, I haven't taken a closer look there.

An alternative solution might be to split this complex logic down to smaller steps, e.g. transfer the file using `scp`, perhaps even to localhost and do the comparison locally.

Comment: I don't think it is caused by special characters, since the file content is firewall rules, there are only characters like semicolon, single/double quotes, dots and so on. Also, maybe one of ten runs it shows uninterrupted content of $fw_orig and diff returns 'match'. I'm guessing it has something to do with how many lines can terminal show, or maybe something with file descriptors etc .. Because as I added later, if I first save my variable $w_orig to file, and later use this file with diff commands, it always works.  so content of $w_orig is correct, only not showed right for some reason ..

Comment: Well, single/double quotes in the file can cause really severe problems due to unsufficient escaping, as I've demonstrated. That being said, the reason for the misbehavior might indeed be different. Could you come up with a self-contained example reproducing the bug (that is, not using files whose contents are unknown to us, not ssh'ing etc.)? It's also unclear to me _where_ exactly the script goes haywire, first it seems it's the assignment to `fw_orig` (the first statement within ssh), yet later you experiment with other variations of `diff`.